# How do I display a new line within column data in an Apex Interactive Report

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I'm using Apex 4.2 and Oracle 11.g

I have a column called "Transaction Detail" that I display in an interactive report.  The report column's Display Text As selection is set to "Standard Report Column".
The report column is selected from a varchar2 table column called transaction_detail.  I'm just building the table as well.  The transaction_detail table column is populated from a Procedure with the following code:

```
Insert into mail_log (transaction_type, transaction_detail)
Values ('FTP Transaction',
           'Filename=' || p_image_filename || 
                '&lt;br/&gt;' || 'Event Description=' || l_event_description);
```

The procedure code can be easily changed.
The report just displays:

> `Filename=myfile.jpg<br/>Event Description=my description`

I've tried using CHR(13) in the procedure instead of the html characters and then tried to replace the CHR(13) in apex with html characters.  Instead of simply selecting the column:

```
  , transaction_detail
```

I tried:

```
 , REPLACE(transaction_detail, CHR(13), '&lt;br/&gt;')
```

but I couldn't get past an Apex error: ORA-12899: value too large for column "APEX_040200"."WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET_COLUMNS"."DB_COLUMN_NAME" (actual: 49, maximum: 30)

Shouldn't Apex be able to interpret the 
 as a new line if the column is a Standard Report Column?

Comment: extended discussion on this already in the more active OTN forums https://community.oracle.com/message/12930627

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was answered on the OTN forum by Jorge (jrimblas) and others.  The link to that discussion is above.  Short summary, In the stored procedure I got rid of the `'&lt;br/&gt;'` and replaced it with `CHR(13)`.  Then, in the Apex interactive report, I did NOT need to change the column to "Standard Report Column".  I placed the following in the "HTML expression" for the column.

```
<div style="width:240px">
<pre style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; white-space:pre-wrap">#TRANSACTION_DETAIL#</pre>
</div>
```